# How can I determine if a contractor has a valid license?

Tags: contractors

Is there a website that you can check to see if a contractor is licensed and is valid?  Is it a state by state thing, or is their a national database as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contractor licensing is by state, and sometimes even more regionally.

Answer (score 4):

Contractor licenses are normally issued by the state.  Get the licence number and call your Secretary of State's Office, usually the corporations and licensing division to check if they are in good standing. Some states require licensed contractors carry liability insurance, some don't, but if you are doing a large project, ask for an insurance binder.

Answer (score 0):

Some states like California have websites that you can search by business name, contractors name or license number.  It well give you a list of choices on name or business searches by name and then by city.  I use Californias a lot for.business use.